# toggleDrawerState with Nativescript-telerik-ui slide drawer

Tags: javascript, telerik, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm using the newest version of Telerik-Nativescript-UI (ver. 1.3.1). This updated version is supposed to support action bar overlap. I'm using the example shown [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/SideDrawer/getting-started#showing-radsidedrawer-over-the-navigation-baraction-bar) to re-work my existing drawer implementation. The issues I'm coming across are my once fully functioning toggle drawer button is no longer working following the update. I'm attempting to call toggleDrawerState() in order to handle this but it's failing when I attempt to get the reference to the drawer. My other issue is the drawer content no longer loads from my widget directory Here is an example of my code below

**XML View**

```
  <dpg:DrawerPage
    navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo"
    navigatingTo="navigatingTo"  
    xmlns:dpg="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/drawerpage"
    xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer"
    xmlns:widgets="shared/widgets"
    xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

  <page.actionBar>
    <action-bar title="{{L('connections')}}">
      <!--<NavigationButton  icon="res://back" tap="goBack" ios:visibility="collapsed" />      -->
      <NavigationButton  icon="res://menu" tap="toggleDrawer" ios:visibility="collapsed" />
      <action-bar.actionItems>
        <ios>
          <action-item icon="res://ic_menu" ios.position="left" tap="toggleDrawer" />
        </ios>
      </action-bar.actionItems>
    </action-bar>
  </page.actionBar>

  <dpg:DrawerPage.sideDrawer id="">
    <drawer:RadSideDrawer id="drawer">
      <drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
        <widgets:drawer-content />
      </drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
    </drawer:RadSideDrawer> 
  </dpg:DrawerPage.sideDrawer>

    <StackLayout cssClass="mainContent">
        <Label text="test test test" textWrap="true" cssClass="drawerContentText"/>

    </StackLayout>
</dpg:DrawerPage>
```

**JS where I attempt to toggle the drawer**

```
SideDrawer.prototype.toggleDrawer = function() {
  var page = topmost().currentPage;
  page.getViewById("drawer").toggleDrawerState();
};
```

Apparently trying to access the drawer by getting the ID attached to `the<drawer:RadSideDrawer id="drawer">` is not the correct, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You could review the code in this example - https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/tree/release/sdk/app/sidedrawer/over-navigation, where has been shown how you could use ActionBar overlap functionality

Comment: @NikolayTsonev I have but it doesn't show how to correctly use the toggleDrawerStateMethod. Based on my above code I don't understand why my current implementation of the toggle feature wouldn't work. Do I need to access the drawer in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario where you are using the "show over ActionBar" feature of the  RadSideDrawer you are no longer adding the `RadSideDrawer` to the Page's `content` but to a property of the custom `DrawerPage`, this is why you can no longer use Page's `.getViewById()` method. In this scenario you can simply cast the Page to a DrawerPage and directly use its `sideDrawer` property which is the declared RadSideDrawer in the XML. For example like this:

```
SideDrawer.prototype.toggleDrawer = function() {
  var page = topmost().currentPage;
  page.sideDrawer.toggleDrawerState();
};
```